# How to install OpenWrt on BT Home Hub 3.0 Type A?

Tags: networking, router, openwrt, firmware

I found an old BT Home Hub 3.0 Type A router in the cupboard and would like to install OpenWrt on it to replace the router we are currently using which suffers very badly from bufferbloat.

I have had a look at [the page on the wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/bt/homehub_v3a) dedicated to this router, but don't see any installation instructions — at least, none I would be able to follow.

I also found [this thread](https://openwrt.ebilan.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=129&start=50#p1784) which seems to discuss how to set up OpenWrt on a Home Hub 3, but I can't follow the thread either, lots of what's talking about goes right over my head.

I have no experience in installing firmware onto routers, and would really appreciate it if someone could suggest a step-by-step list of instructions I'd have to go through to set up this system.

My starting point: factory-reset home hub and 15" Macbook in hands, with another router (technicolor TG589vac) running downstairs providing me with the internet connection I am using to ask this question.

Thank you all so much for any help you may provide, as a noob at this I'd greatly appreciate any tips and pointers.

Comment: It's dangerous to brick your device, if something is wrong. Maybe this site could be helpful: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.flashing   Or if would be interested in dd-wrt : https://dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Broadcom_detection

Comment: @GiaRui Why is it dangerous? I have no other purpose for this router. Also, dd-wrt doesn't support this router.

Comment: The risk to brick it, is described in the link I posted. Try to install the firmware thru the "upgrade firmware" feature, you need to login to your router.